# Перенос файла в окно программы

Tags: java

Есть программа, где по нажатию на кнопку можно загрузить файл. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было файл просто перетащить на окно и он загрузился?

Comment: Добавить в программу обработчик события перетаскивания.

Comment: Или используй готовый скрипт, например такой: [смотреть пример](https://www.plupload.com/examples/)

Comment: @Роман Java и Javascript - два разных языка, у которых общего - только 4 буквы.